# Click on a div to make another appear and hide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created two divs in the body tag. The one div is not visible, but I want it to become visible by clicking on the other div as well as it to disappear by clicking that div again. Basically div2 is not visible when the page loads, I want it to become visible and hidden by clicking div1. Please Help.
Thank you!

HTML:

```
 <div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: orange;
}

#div2{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: blue;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: Do you want to achieve it without JS?

Comment: @hamzox I would like to, but if this is not possible I would appreciate any answer, even if it contains Javascript.

Comment: @Chenius Please edit and add the tag `javascript` to this question also.

Comment: @SaifUrRahman Did it right now, as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a extra class like `hidden`, then toggle that class on click of `div1`. Note that this answer uses javascript, without it it's not possible to make the change like you've described it in your question.

```js
document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('div2').classList.toggle('hidden');
}, false);
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}

#div2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Foo</div>
<div id="div2" class="hidden">Bar</div>
```

Comment: The question is not tagged Javascript.

Comment: Thanks @connexo. I've edited the answer to explain why it uses js

Comment: Thank you to everyone who commented and tried to help, it is appreciated!

Comment: `e => {
  document.getElementById('div2').classList.toggle('hidden');
}` should be `() => {
  document.getElementById('div2').classList.toggle('hidden');
}` since you're never using `e`.

Comment: Kannst du mir den Vorteil davon erklären? @connexo

Comment: It's considered good practice to not define variables that are never used. This includes implicit variable declarations like in case of named parameters. You will find this practice in just about any linting preset. Also read https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars

Comment: Yeah, you got a point. I've disabled the rule for arrows because my IDE autogenerates them.. @connexo

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS without any further changes you can make it so as long as `#div1` has `mouseDown` on it, `#div2` becomes visible.

```css
#div1{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}

#div2{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#div1:active + #div2 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Nice solution but from what the OP described they want to click, not hold the mouse down, to show the second div

Answer (score 1):

You can add the javscript script given below within `<script>` tags.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("div2");
    if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
        x.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        x.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

```css
#div1{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: orange;
}

#div2{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: blue;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: OP's using `visibility`, not `display`.

Comment: I know. I find it better using display, that's why I have used `display`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in the following way too.

```js
<script>
           
    function toggleFunction() {

      var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
      var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
      if (div1.style.display === "none") {
          div1.style.display = "block";
          div2.style.display ="none";

      } else {
          div1.style.display = "none";
          div2.style.display="block";
      }
   }
</script>
```

```html
<div id="div1" onclick="toggleFunction();">div1</div>
<div id="div2" onclick="toggleFunction();">div2</div>
```

Comment: OP's using `visibility`, not `display`.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered, and the answer works well. I wanted to share one other workaround that is just strictly CSS. It's commonly referred to as the "`checkbox hack`", which was pretty popular a few years back (a ton of demos were made of whack-a-mole type games where no JS was used).

The idea is that you use a combination label/checkbox, which applies `state` (checkbox) to your DOM and that `state` is represented visually using the `:checked` pseudo class. For your example, we could modify the mark up and include our input/label like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="triggerVisibility"></input>

<div id="div1">
    <label for="triggerVisibility" id="label1"></label>
</div>

<div id="div2"></div>
```

One important thing to notice is that your checkbox should be BEFORE the element you want to apply "state" to. That's because, for the CSS, we'll use a `sibling` selector (either `+` or `~`)

```
#triggerVisibility:checked ~ #div2 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

In our case, we're using the more "relaxed" general sibling selector (`~`), which means anything that follows the input with id "triggerVisibility" will have visibility set to visible, when the checkbox is checked. Pretty cool, huh?

Here's a fiddle that includes other "state" (like content) that we change when the input is checked/unchecked:

http://jsfiddle.net/nrwqh5tp/

Comment: Thank you for this addition!

Answer (score -1):

Go through here for full details:

```js
$("#div1").click(function(){
 // alert("hi");
  $("#div2").toggleClass("Active");
  
});
```

```css
#div1{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: orange;
cursor:pointer
}

#div2{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: blue;
visibility: hidden;
}
.Active{
  visibility: visible!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>

<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```